# Upper bound for integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the intagrel $$\int_{|x-y|}^{2|x|}{\frac{s}{s^{\gamma}}\left(\frac{s+|x|}{s}\right)^{\alpha}}ds,$$ where $0<\gamma\leq 2$ and $\alpha>0$. I am looking for a "good" estimate of an upper bound of this integral depending on $x$ and $y$. Has someone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming your variables
to make it easier,
and assuming that
$2|x| > |x-y|$,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{|x-y|}^{2|x|}{\dfrac{s}{s^c}\left(\frac{s+|x|}{s}\right)^a}ds
&=\int_{|x-y|}^{2|x|}s^{1-a-c}(s+|x|)^cds\\
&=\int_{|x-y|}^{2|x|}s^b(s+|x|)^cds
\qquad b=1-a-c\\
&\le (2|x|-|x-y|)(2|x|)^b(2|x|+|x|)^c\\
&= (2|x|-|x-y|)(2|x|)^b(3|x|)^c\\
&= (2|x|-|x-y|)2^b3^c|x|^{b+c}\\
&= (2|x|-|x-y|)2^{1-a-c}3^c|x|^{1-a}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: How do you know that $sup_{s \in [|x-y|, 2|x|]}(s^{b})=(2|x|)^{b}$?

Comment: I added the assumption that $2|x| > |x-y|$. If this is not true, e.g., $y > 3|x|$, then this bound has to be modified.

Comment: But $b<0$ is possible, or not?... then this is not the case?

Comment: Yes, if a + c > 1.